# sqlite query help

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I have 1 table.

```
jobs = ref( int primary key autoincrement ) 
      _id(int)
      date(date)
```

_id represents a particular car. each row in the table represents a job for a car including the date the job happened. 1 car can have lots of jobs.

I need 2 sqlite commands

1. command which would get me the most recent job for each and every car in the table.
2. command which would get me all cars which have not had a job for the past 21 days.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most recent job:

```
 SELECT _id, max(date) FROM jobs GROUP BY _id
```

All cars with no job in last 21 days:

```
 SELECT _id, max(date) FROM jobs GROUP BY _id HAVING max(date) < (date-21)
```

You'll have to adopt the (date-21) logic depending on how you store dates (SQLite doesn't have a native DATE type).

Comment: sorry i wasnt so clear, i actually  need 2 commands, i edited my post thanks Larry

Comment: thanks the commands work fine in sqlite3 shell, but in android the cursor/listview will only work if i bind the _id column :S it wont let me display date, however a simple SELECT * FROM tb1 will populate both columns of the cursor/listview, any ideas Larry? i really appreciate your help

Comment: Not familiar with Android development, but at a guess it has to do with the return type of the MAX(Date) not being whatever you expect a date to look like (SQLite is very funny about data types).  Try examining the data type of that column if you can, and casting it to date with one of the SQLite date functions.

Comment: ok thanks for all your jelp, the select statments are fine i will fiddle with it o/